# when I hit my node JS API from Heroku live server, CORS policy error is coming

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku, cors

when I hit my node js API from the angular app(which is in local setup) and I keep my node js API in Heroku live server, I am getting this error. CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
but at the same time, when I keep my API in the AWS server or local server setup, I am not getting any errors. everything is working well.
I installed cors and used the setHeader, in my API, I am attaching the image of the error and code, please help me to get the solution of this.

**I'm using this code for allow-access-header**

```
    // Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

   // Request methods you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD,PATCH, DELETE');

   // Request headers you wish to allow
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

   // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
   // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

   // Pass to next layer of middleware
   next();
});
```

**Here Im using this API**

```
app.get("/getNoOfUsersGuardians",(request, response) => {
    let userArr = [];
    let _userData = [];
    database.collection("_User").find().toArray((error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return response.json({ status: false, data: '', message: error });
        }
        _userData = result;
        var j = 1;
    // console.log(_userData[0]);
       for (var i = 0; i < _userData.length; i++){
            var userId = "_User$"+_userData[i]['_id'];
            let name=_userData[i]['name'];
            let username=_userData[i]['username'];
            let userEmail = _userData[i]['email'];
            let mobileno=_userData[i]['phoneNumber'];
            let phonecountrycode=_userData[i]['phoneCountryCode'];
            let _updated_At =_userData[i]['_updated_at'];
            database.collection("GuardianInvitation").find({_p_fromUser: userId, status:"accepted"}).count((error, result1)=>{
                if(result1)
                {
                    database.collection("_Session").findOne({_p_user: userId}, function(err, resultdevice) {
                        if (resultdevice) {
                   tempuserArr={ };
                   tempuserArr.userid=userId;
                   tempuserArr.username=username;
                   tempuserArr.name=name;
                   tempuserArr.mobileno=mobileno;
                   tempuserArr.userEmail=userEmail;
                   tempuserArr.phoneCountryCode=phonecountrycode;
                   tempuserArr._updated_at = _updated_At;
                   tempuserArr.NoofGuardian=result1;
                   tempuserArr.device=resultdevice["device"];
                   userArr.push(tempuserArr);
                         }
                     });
                }
                j++;
                if(_userData.length == j){
                    if(userArr.length > 0){
                        response.send({ status: true, data: userArr, message: 'User liSt found that have Number of guardians' });
                    } else {
                        response.send({ status: false, data: "", message: 'Guardians list not found' });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Plz, check the image here...**
[Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJ8s.png)

Comment: Why don't you instead install the `cors` package from npm, import it `const cors = require('cors')` and use it like so: `app.use(cors())`

Comment: @hacKaTun3s  i'm already install `cors` and use `var cors = require('cors');` and use like this `app.use(cors());`

Comment: So why do u use this code then? - "I'm using this code for allow-access-header"

Comment: when we hit API from another server to another server then error comes like cross-origin-access-header, that's why we use this code and error not coming, but in my case error are coming only heroku server, when I hit this API from was server error was not come

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add node cors options like this

```
const corsOptions = {
 origin: '*',
 methods: [
  'GET',
  'POST',
 ],
 allowedHeaders: [
  'Content-Type',
 ],
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: i used your code on my server-side but getting this issue in some times, how can I resolve this?

Comment: If you using node cors like this remove mentioned header adding part to the app. also add all the methods and headers to corsOption object.
 You can try both ways either this or your mentioned way. 
But you need to make sure you are adding this before routes are defined.